# Populating column with Excel formula

Tags: python, excel

I'm fairly new to python.

I have been struggling with getting an excel formula to actually populate the formula in my spreadsheet. What I'm trying to do is in column1 if it contains the word dog, the corresponding column populates with blue and if column one contains the word cat that column2 populates with red.

Snippets from my code because it's stored elsewhere unless I need to rewrite it from top to bottom, just let me know.

I started off by creating a new column but I want to populate the row with a formula.

`df.insert(2, 'Column2', "")`

The actual Excel code I want to use `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("dog", A2)), blue, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cat", H2)), red, "NOT FOUND")`

I've tried `worksheet.write_formula('B2', 'IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("dog", A2)), blue, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cat", H2)), red, "NOT FOUND"))`

and `df.append({"B2": 'IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("dog", A2)), blue, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cat", H2)), red, "NOT FOUND")}, ignore_index=True)`

among others that I don't remember. I'm also trying to populate the whole column. Any insight would be very much appreciated. Everything I've tried so far either doesn't populate the cell or posts the code as a text.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Yes I have xlsxwriter, pandas, and numpy imported.

Comment: Do you need to create the formula using xlsxwriter or can you just populate the values using pandas and save the file?

Comment: I don't think it matters but I'm also not 100% sure. What I've tried above isn't working for me.

Comment: use [numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html): `df['new_col'] = np.select([df['column1'] == 'dog', df['column1'] == 'cat'], ['blue', 'red'], np.nan)` So it means if column 1 is equal to dog then blue else if column 1 is equal to cat then red else NULL.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with using Conditional Formatting?

[image: Conditional Formatting]

In the words of Tom Scott *(AKA an absolute legend)* "Why code things that already exist?"

Comment: I need it to populate a different column while still maintaining the original column because the data will be manipulated into a different program where the values are required.

Comment: The conditional formatting is on a seperate column doesn't have to be on the B Col. I am mildly confused by what you mean.